# I need help to choose between GLM and LMM or GLMM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution, glmm

I have a dataset of 200 subjects, who were divided into a control arm and a treatment arm (100 per arm).

I am investigating the incidence of pain above a certain threshold, so i was thinking if using a binomial glm.

Problem is, i have one of my variables as a longitudinal variable: at time 0, at 3 months and at 6 months, as a covariate.

I have two options as i see it:

1. disregard this covariate, and use a binomial glm. If so i was to use the pain at time 0 as a covariate
2. use a mixed model. However my response variable is calculated from the pain at 6 months. In that case, i was going to use the pain score as a response variable, and adjust by time period.

I am just starting to learn on lmm, so any help is appreciated.

I would also need to learn how to detect outliers with lmm.